# Subversion (svn) repository on NTFS partition in Linux?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, ntfs, ext4

Can I create and use an svn repository on an NTFS partition when working with svn in Linux? That is, repository on the NTFS partition and checkouts and commits to and from an EXT4 partition.

I realize that NTFS support in Linux is limited and does not support permissions and symbolic links for example. Would that, or any other limitations, cause any issues?

The reason I am asking is because I am thinking about either 1) moving my repository to my Dropbox folder (which resides on an NTFS partition) or 2) moving my repository to a memory stick (which could potentially be NTFS partitioned).

My use case is very simple. I am the only person using the repository. Currently my repository resides on EXT4 and I either access it from the same machine as the repository is located on, or from a second machine thorough svn+ssh://. However, if I went with one of the options above, the access strategy would obviously change.

Answer (score 2):

I would be hesitant to do this because, as you stated, NTFS partitions don't support Unix style permissions.

The Subversion repository directory is usually owned and can only be written to by the user who runs whatever Subversion server process is running. For example, if you're using Apache httpd, and you're Apache user is called *httpd*, the user who owns the repository is *httpd* and this would be the only user with write permissions on the files and directories.

A NTFS partition on a Windows box does have permissions set correctly because the Subversion server process would use Windows permission settings. A Linux server will have problems.

Also NTFS partitions are *case preserving* and not *case sensitive*, I don't know how this would affect the Subversion server process running on a Linux box. Again, a Windows Subversion server process would be fine with this. A Linux server may have problems.

Unfortunately, I can't say for certain one way or another. I've never tried it, nor seen it done. However, there is a post on the [Wandisco Forum](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/38125-SVN-error-on-NTFS-partition-from-Linux) that covers this very scenario. The user was able to get around his problems, but I would be hesitant to say that all is beer and candy from then on.

Please say you're not doing this, so you can share a `file://` protocol Subversion repository among multiple users. This is a big, fat no-no. Instead, you should at least run the `svnserve` process, and have users accessing your repository via the `svn://` protocol. It's very simple to setup `svnserve` -- even as a Windows service. The only problem may be that port 3620 (The Subversion server port) is being blocked by your firewall or router.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. My use case is very simple and specific (single user, two machines). Sorry, I should have made this clear in my question (now updated). So, some of the issues you mention are probably not relevant?

Comment: Even in such a limited setup, I would still recommend against using a non-native filesystem for this application. I would also recommend against putting your repository on Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on the potential problems?

Comment: The problem stems from several things: First is that hooks may not execute correctly. Second is that there's no protection from someone from directly munging the actual repository. Someone could make changes in the code, and not have the changes logged in Subversion. Third is a potential collision between two commits that occur at the same time. If you're a single user doing two different systems, one at a time, these _probably_ won't be an issue. However, I use Subversion on an like this and still run `svnserve` just to shorten URLs. `svn://localhost/...` instead of `file:///Z:\blah\blah\...`

Answer (score -1):

Dropbox multiboot ntfs folder sync.

In an earlier closed thread by vanadium people we're wanting solution to sync Dropbox on multiple boot systems in one ntfs directory. Vanadium had a good suggestion that I tweaked a little bit to solve.

1. You must install it in Windows or other system and setup Dropbox folder from Dropbox.
2. Reboot into Linux system. (I used Ubuntu 18)
3. Install Dropbox to Ext 4 partition.
4. Open file manager to Home folder and delete Dropbox directory. Leave this file manager open.
5. Open a new file manager to the main directory ntfs or other that other os Dropbox folder is in.
6. Hit ctr + h then drag the Dropbox folder to the directory you deleted it from. (This creates a symbol link shortcut to the Dropbox folder you want)
7. Now sync Dropbox in Linux.
8. If you want Dropbox to load at startup you must set the partition folder to auto mount on startup in terminal.

1 - Write down the UUID of the drive that you want to mount by executing the following command:

sudo blkid
2 - Then edit the fstab:

sudo gedit /etc/fstab
3 - Add at the end of the file fstab:

UUID=D638F77338F7514B /media/baraldi/win_www ntfs defaults 0 0
Be sure the UUID matches what you recorded in the first step

4 - Restart)

Or Use the "Disks" app.

Load the Disks app (In System) and select the disk with the filesystem you want to mount on startup.

Then select the filesystem on that disk and click on the gears (for configuration).

Select "Edit Mount Options" from the popup menu.

On the setup options, click to check the "Mount on Startup" box. (This will add the entry to fstab when you click on "OK").

Reboot, and your filesystem should be available.

I agree with other comments here regarding manually adding lines to fstab via CLI/text editor. If you take the time to look at your fstab file it will help you understand what changes have been made and, ultimately the CLI method will become faster for you.